# Microstream issue Could not obtain access to "jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe"

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut, microstream

I'm doing my first steps using Microstream in a Micronaut application (JDK 17).

I have implemented the following repository

```java
@Singleton
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultWritableProductRepository implements WritableProductRepository {

  private final StorageManager storageManager;

  @Override
  public Product save(Product product) { // Product is an interface

    data().getProducts().put(product.id(), product);
    storageManager.store(data().getProducts());
    return product;
  }

  private RootData data() {
    return (RootData) storageManager.root();
  }
}
```

And my data root to store the data.

```java
@Introspected
public class RootData {

  private Map<UUID, Product> products = new HashMap<>();

  @NotNull
  public Map<UUID, Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
  }
}
```

When I store a product I get an `IllegalAccessException` since Microstream wants to access `jdk.internal.misc` but that's of course no allowed by default.

```
15:36:20.222 [MicroStream-StorageChannel-0] DEBUG o.m.s.t.StorageEntityCache$Default - Consolidated StorageEntityCache to 1 entries!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Could not obtain access to "jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe", please start the VM with --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.createInternalVM(JdkInternals.java:920)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.internalVM(JdkInternals.java:896)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.lookupInternalObjectFieldOffsetMethod(JdkInternals.java:948)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.internalObjectFieldOffsetMethod(JdkInternals.java:937)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.objectFieldOffset(JdkInternals.java:975)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.objectFieldOffsets(JdkInternals.java:1002)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkMemoryAccessor.objectFieldOffsets(JdkMemoryAccessor.java:540)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkMemoryAccessor.objectFieldOffsets(JdkMemoryAccessor.java:554)
    at one.microstream.memory.XMemory.objectFieldOffsets(XMemory.java:652)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.objectFieldOffsets(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:183)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.initializeStoringMemoryOffsets(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:335)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.<init>(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:298)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.BinaryHandlerGenericType.<init>(BinaryHandlerGenericType.java:84)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.BinaryHandlerGenericType.New(BinaryHandlerGenericType.java:47)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryTypeHandlerCreator$Default.internalCreateTypeHandlerGeneric(BinaryTypeHandlerCreator.java:257)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator$Abstract.createTypeHandlerGeneric(PersistenceTypeHandlerCreator.java:185)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerEnsurer$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerEnsurer.java:257)
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.java:191)
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.provideTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerProviderCreating.java:99)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.internalEnsureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:615)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:384)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:360)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.registerGuaranteed(BinaryStorer.java:618)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.registerLazyOptional(BinaryStorer.java:633)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceObjectManager$Default.ensureObjectId(PersistenceObjectManager.java:202)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.register(BinaryStorer.java:652)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.apply(BinaryStorer.java:328)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.Binary.storeMapEntrySet(Binary.java:536)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.jdk8.java.util.BinaryHandlerHashMap.store(BinaryHandlerHashMap.java:105)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.jdk8.java.util.BinaryHandlerHashMap.store(BinaryHandlerHashMap.java:1)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerCustom.store(AbstractBinaryHandlerCustom.java:1)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.storeItem(BinaryStorer.java:459)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.storeGraph(BinaryStorer.java:442)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.types.BinaryStorer$Default.store(BinaryStorer.java:466)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceManager$Default.store(PersistenceManager.java:304)
    at one.microstream.storage.types.StorageConnection.store(StorageConnection.java:381)
    at ch.onstructive.salessystem.productengine.db.loader.DefaultWritableProductRepository.save(DefaultWritableProductRepository.java:32)
    at ch.onstructive.salessystem.productengine.db.loader.datatransformers.AbstractDataTransformer.persist(AbstractDataTransformer.java:98)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at ch.onstructive.salessystem.productengine.db.loader.datatransformers.AbstractDataTransformer.transformAndPersist(AbstractDataTransformer.java:85)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at ch.onstructive.salessystem.productengine.db.loader.ProductLoaderCommand.run(ProductLoaderCommand.java:58)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner.run(PicocliRunner.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner.run(PicocliRunner.java:114)
    at ch.onstructive.salessystem.productengine.db.loader.ProductLoaderCommand.main(ProductLoaderCommand.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @355ce81c
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:709)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at one.microstream.memory.sun.JdkInternals.createInternalVM(JdkInternals.java:909)
    ... 61 more
```

When I start the Micronaut application adding the VM option `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED` everything works fine.

As mentioned in the listing above the type `Product` is an interface and something in this data structure triggers the error. The actual implementation of `Product` is a Java record called `DefaultProduct`.

```java
@Introspected
public record DefaultProduct(
    @NotNull UUID id,
    @NotNull LocalDate validFrom,
    @NotNull LocalDate validUntil,
    @NotNull @NotBlank String name,
    @NotNull @NotEmpty List<PriceElement> priceElements,
    @NotNull @NotEmpty Set<Criterion> criteria,
    @NotNull LegalBasis legalBasis)
    implements Product {}
```

I have replaced the map in `RootData` from `Map<UUID, Product>` to `Map<UUID, String>` and the problem is gone without using `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED`, so it has clearly to do with my data structure `Product`.

The problem is I cannot run my tests using Gradle, even if I tell the JVM to add that option.

```
tasks.named('test') {
    jvmArgs ['--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```

So I have the following questions:

1. Does anyone have a clue why Microstream needs to access that and point me the directions what could probably be wrong?
2. Is there a way to run the my tests in the Gradle build and add the VM option, so the tests can be executed and workaround the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has something todo with Java Records. When converting the Java Record to POJOs the error is not provoked.

```java
@Introspected
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DefaultProduct implements Product {
  private @NotNull UUID id;
  private @NotNull LocalDate validFrom;
  private @NotNull LocalDate validUntil;
  private @NotNull @NotBlank String name;
  private @NotNull @NotEmpty List<PriceElement> priceElements;
  private @NotNull @NotEmpty Set<Criterion> criteria;
  private @NotNull LegalBasis legalBasis;
}
```

The reason for the error is described in the [Microstream FAQ](https://docs.microstream.one/manual/storage/faq/java-features.html).

> Can MicroStream handle Records?
> Yes, but due to reflection restrictions of records introduced in Java 15 an export has to be added to the VM parameters:
> --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED